# Configure a bridged Ethernet adapter in a VirtualBox guest running Scientific Linux

Tags: networking, virtualbox, ip, ethernet, scientific-linux

I installed Scientific Linux 6.2 x86 in VirtualBox on Windows 7 x64.

The adapter is

```
Adapter 1: Paravirtualized Network (Bridged adapter, Marvell Yukon 88E8056 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller)
promiscuous mode: Deny
```

But this adapter does not get ip address.

```
[root@server ~]# ifconfig -a
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:40:5A:33:F2:92  
          inet6 addr: fe80::240:5aff:fe33:f292/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:398 (398.0 b)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:960 (960.0 b)  TX bytes:960 (960.0 b)
```

The list of `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts`

```
[root@server network-scripts]# ls
ifcfg-eth0   ifdown-eth   ifdown-ppp     ifup-aliases  ifup-isdn   ifup-routes       net.hotplug
ifcfg-eth1   ifdown-ippp  ifdown-routes  ifup-bnep     ifup-plip   ifup-sit          network-functions
ifcfg-lo     ifdown-ipv6  ifdown-sit     ifup-eth      ifup-plusb  ifup-tunnel       network-functions-ipv6
ifdown       ifdown-isdn  ifdown-tunnel  ifup-ippp     ifup-post   ifup-wireless
ifdown-bnep  ifdown-post  ifup           ifup-ipv6     ifup-ppp    init.ipv6-global
```

And `ifcfg-eth1` is

```
DEVICE=eth1
HWADDR=00:40:5a:33:f2:92
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
ONBOOT=no
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
TYPE=Ethernet
USERCTL=no
PEERDNS=yes
IPV6INIT=no
```

Please let me know how to get eth1's IP address 192.168.0.x.

Comment: What kind of NIC does the guest see?  I've only had luck with the Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop one, although I don't remember the specific problems I had with the other types.   I'm also using a Marvell Yukon 88E8056 PCI-E adapter on a Window 7 x64 host, and a variety of Linux/Solaris/*BSD guests.

Comment: Scott McClung/ virtio - Paravirtualized Network. I will try "Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop".

Comment: "service network restart", then I got "Bringing up interface eth0:  RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument"

Comment: I will check my configuration when I can.  I do not think I have seen that message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, just enter the IP address yourself:

```
ifconfig eth1 192.168.0.x
```

If it doesn't work, go into the setting of the specific virtual drive and enable your network option through one of your virtual adapters.

Comment: Secko/ Thanks for your opinion, but still broke network. As you said, I should check network settings.

Comment: @WindStory If you checked your network settings, can you ping anything in your own network?!

Answer (score 1):

More likely you forget to enable promiscuous on adapter:

[image]

By default, sniffering is denied.